# VBA-EXCEL Defining Ranges with variables

Tags: vba, excel

**Problem:** I am unable to define a range using a variable (i) and specific cells row (cell.Row).

**Current Code:**

```
Sub TaskSearch()
'Dim wb As Workbook
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Range


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interface").Range("D19:D33").ClearContents

'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Kevin.Boots\Database.xlsx")
Set oSht = Sheets("TaskMaster")
lastRow = oSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
strSearch = Sheets("Interface").Range("F5")

Set aCell = oSht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

  Sheets("Interface").Range("D19").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("C" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D20").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("D" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D21").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("E" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D22").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("F" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D23").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("G" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D24").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("H" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D25").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("I" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D26").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("J" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D27").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("K" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D28").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("L" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D29").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("M" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D30").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("N" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D31").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("O" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D32").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("P" & aCell.Row).Value
  Sheets("Interface").Range("D33").Value = Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("Q" & aCell.Row).Value

Exit Sub
```

End Sub

**Objective:** I am attempting to make this code more robust. Part of reasoning is for me to be able to skip blanks. This is a nightmare when trying to adjust cells.

I have tried two different methods to accomplish this:

**Method A:**

```
wb.Sheets("Interface").Range("D19:D33").Copy
  wb.Sheets("TaskMaster").Range("C" & aCell.Row & ":Q" & aCell.Row).PastSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True
```

**Failure:** Runtime Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

**Method B:**

```
   For j = 3 To 16
    If Not IsEmpty(j, aCell.Row) Then
        For i = 19 To 33

            iWb.oSht.Range(j, aCell.Row).Value = _
           iWb.iSht.Range(4, i).Value

        Next i
    End If
Next j

Exit Sub
```

**Failure:** ( I cant get this older version to compile again) I believe the error arose with issues defining the range.

To summarize I am trying to find the fastest method to transfer information from one worksheet to another worksheet using the `.find`. I am also trying to not copy blank cells while transferring.

I currently believe this method will be the best suited for my application.

```
Sub TSearch()
Dim dWb As Workbook, Wb As Workbook
Dim oSht As Worksheet, Sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Variant
Dim cell As Variant
'On Error GoTo Err

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interface").Range("D19:D33").ClearContents

'Set dWb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Kevin.Boots\Database.xlsx")
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = Sheets("TaskMaster") ' Reference Worksheet
Set oSht = Sheets("Interface") ' User Interface Worksheet

lastRow = Sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Obtain Last row of reference Worksheet
strSearch = oSht.Range("F5") 'Obtain User Selected Search Criteria

Set aCell = Sht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

For j = 3 To 16 'Columns from Reference Worksheet to be transfered
    If Not IsEmpty(Wb.Sht.Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then ' Verify If cell has value before transfering
        For i = 19 To 33 ' Rows of User Interface where values are to be transfered
            Wb.Sht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = _
            Wb.oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value

        Next i
    End If
  Next j
 Exit Sub

 'Err: 'MsgBox " Generic Task not found" & vbCrLf

 End Sub
```

The `IEmpty` Function is still causing an error 438: Object doesn't support this property method. If I remove the `IsEmpty` then 
'Wb.Sht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = Wb.oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value' gives me the same error.

Comment: What is the value of `aCell`?

Comment: My apologies, the workbooks are poorly defined as I have been trying to preserve my ability to later transfer my information over to a database. However they have been verified to be correct.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend copying and pasting but your Method A has a typo which might be causing the error. You've used `PastSpecial` instead of `PasteSpecial`

Comment: My question still remains. If your `.Find` returns more than one cell, I don't believe `aCell.Row` will work, and if it does, it won't in the context of `Range("A" & ....`)

Comment: With your Method B you are following the parameters of `Cells()`, not `Range()`. Use `Cells()` instead which accepts the parameters in this order: `Cells([row_index], [column_index])`. So something like `iWb.oSht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = iWb.iSht.Range(i, 4).Value`

Comment: @Kyle the value is currently 10, I have it on the watch screen. It is a Variant / Long value type.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you for the advise. I am still relatively new to VBA and am trying to get my head around the parameters for cell vs range.

Comment: Ah, you need to pass a variable through this, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264227.aspx). Try: `IsEmpty(iWb.iSht.Cells(aCell.Row, j))`

Comment: @Jordan, Thank you. `iWb.oSht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = _
                iWb.iSht.Cells(i, 4).Value` is pulling up error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Do you have `End Sub` anywhere? I only see `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Kyle, Yes End Sub didn't seem to stay in the code block when I imported the code.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, does your current code work, and you just can't get the loop to work?

Comment: @ Kyle The current code works, but it copies blank cells from the one worksheet to the other. I have tried several approaches to remove blank cells but am currently not having much luck. After taking all of this input into account I have updated the code, please see question for new code.

Comment: Then something isn't as you say. All your code is valid. Part of you problem is the lack of references. `Set Sht = Sheets("TaskMaster")` should likely be `Set Sht = wb.Sheets("TaskMaster")`.

Comment: I still think it has to do with `aCell`. Are you sure that is holding a single cell and not a range of all matches?

Comment: @Kyle `aCell.Row` has a current value of 14, the search criteria is a long string of text from a drop down list. However the expression aCell.Row is type Variant/Long, could this make a difference.

Comment: @Kyle to test your theory I set aCell.Row to 14. The code still resulted in Run Time error 438 on line `Wb.Sht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = Wb.oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value`

Comment: Then something is wrong with `Sht` or `oSht` or `Wb`...

Comment: @kyle When running the code `Wb = ThisWorkbook`, `Sht=Sheet6`, and `oSht=Sheet5`, all appear on my Watches. I am struggling with even finding a method to simplify and rebuild the code

Comment: Try qualifying `IsEmpty` with `VBA`. So it would be `VBA.IsEmpty()`.

Comment: @Kyle You were correct `aCell` was causing the issue. It appears that since aCell is defined within a workbook and a worksheet those values cannot be redefined. `For j = 3 To 16                                     
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then
            i = j + 16
                oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value
        End If
    Next j` complies perfectly.

Comment: `.Row` is a property of a range and is immutable, so you are correct that you cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop won't work due to `IsEmpty` which expects a single cell or variable to check, but you are giving it two numbers. The below should work, but some things aren't qualified, so you may still run into issues. Also, `Range()` expects either two ranges to be provided, or a range string. I think you were looking for `Cells()`, which accepts a row (as a number) as the first parameter and a column (as a number) as the second.

```
For j = 3 To 16
    If Not IsEmpty(cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then
        For i = 19 To 33

            iWb.oSht.Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value = _
           iWb.iSht.Cells(4, i).Value

        Next i
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: I have updated the code accordingly, however do I need to reference the workbook and sheet for `IsEmpty` like so `If Not IsEmpty(Wb.Sht.Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then` Am I correct to note that the ros is the first index followed by the column. In which case I have made the correct changes.

Comment: You don't *have* to qualify the workbook and sheet ever, but it is good form to do so. In this case, I certainly would. You are also correct that `.Cells()` is row first, then column. I have adjusted my example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the errors were a result of trying to define something that was defined.

```
Sub TSearch()
Dim dWb As Workbook, Wb As Workbook
Dim oSht As Worksheet, Sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim aCell As Variant
Dim cell As Variant
'On Error GoTo Err

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Interface").Range("D19:D33").ClearContents

'Set dWb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Kevin.Boots\Database.xlsx")
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Sht = Sheets("TaskMaster")                      ' Reference Worksheet
Set oSht = Sheets("Interface")                      ' User Interface Worksheet

lastRow = Sht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Obtain Last row of reference Worksheet
strSearch = oSht.Range("F5")                        'Obtain User Selected Search Criteria

 'Find Row in Reference Worksheet that Matches Search Criteria
Set aCell = Sht.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

For j = 3 To 16
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(aCell.Row, j)) Then
        i = j + 16
            oSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(aCell.Row, j).Value
    End If
Next j

 Exit Sub

 'Err:
'MsgBox " Generic Task not found" & vbCrLf

 End Sub
```

Thank you to @Jordan and @Kyle for helping solve this issue.